# What is a group created by app in Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to invite people to a secret group using the Graph API.
As stated in the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/group/members) under **Publishing**.

It says:

> Apps can invite people (if they are an admin, developer, or tester of the app) to a group created by that app using this edge:

I created an App in the [dev console](http://developers.facebook.com) and have the `access_token` for that Aoo.

**My question** is that how do I create this group that the newly created App would have the rights to invite people using the Graph API?

In the end the invite url would look like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<GROUP_ID>/members?access_token=<APP_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

With POST content of:

```
{
   "object": {
      "member": <MEMBER_ID_TO_INVITE>
   }
}
```

Thanks for any pointers, references and answers.

Comment: All you had to do was _click the link_ inside the message that you yourself quoted here ...

Comment: To do what? I know the App and Game Groups are deprecated but my question was more general: Is there and if so how do I create a group that I can send invites using the Graph API.

Comment: _“To do what?”_ - to add two and two together, and draw the logical conclusion …?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/app/groups

> App and Game Groups are deprecated. API access for new apps will be closed on May 1, 2016. Game and App Groups will be deprecated for all apps on October 17, 2016.

In other words, App groups do not exist anymore.